# VBE Start macro on startup and then after that, once a certain column (G) is edited everyday

Tags: excel, vba

In VBE, I have a spreadsheet where if the column 'I' reaches 'MyLimit_', then i will automatically get an email. I am trying to make this code run only when I change a certain column (G).

This code is for the sheet.
In column I, I am looking at the these values to see if they equal my limit. if they do, it will trigger and email being generated.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim FormulaRange As Range
    Dim NotSentMsg As String
    Dim MyMsg As String
    Dim SentMsg As String
    Dim MyLimita As Double
    Dim MyLimitb As Double
    Dim MyLimitc As Double
    Dim MyLimitd As Double



    NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
    SentMsg = "Sent"

'Above the MyLimit value it will run the macro
    MyLimita = 100
    MyLimitb = 50
    MyLimitc = 10
    MyLimitd = 1

'Set the range with Formulas that you want to check
'This is the column that shows how many days left


    Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("I5:I25")


    On Error GoTo EndMacro:
    For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
        With FormulaCell
            If IsNumeric(.Value) = False Then
                MyMsg = ""
            ElseIf .Value = MyLimita Then
                    MyMsg = SentMsg
                    If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                        Call Mail_with_outlook
                    End If
            ElseIf .Value = MyLimitb Then
                    MyMsg = SentMsg
                    If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                        Call Mail_with_outlook
                    End If
            ElseIf .Value = MyLimitc Then
                    MyMsg = SentMsg
                    If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                        Call Mail_with_outlook
                    End If
            ElseIf .Value = MyLimitd Then
                    MyMsg = SentMsg
                    If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                        Call Mail_with_outlook
                    End If
            Else
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With
    Next FormulaCell

 ExitMacro:
    Exit Sub

 EndMacro:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
        & vbLf & Err.Number _
        & vbLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

This code is what I put into the module. This is basically all the code I used to generate my email and then populate with the appropriate info.

```
Option Explicit

Public FormulaCell As Range

Sub Mail_with_outlook()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strto As String, strcc As String, strbcc As String
    Dim strsub As String, strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'Change the parenthesis for column that the email is in

    strto = Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "L").Value
    strcc = ""
    strbcc = ""
    strsub = "Payment Notification (PO --Enter PO # Here--)"

'Change the parenthesis for the Column that the POC is in 

    strbody = "Hi " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "K").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "This is a reminder to pay for a licensing/maintenance bill in: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "I").Value & " days." & _
            vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Line 2" & _
            vbNewLine & "Line 3" & _
            vbNewLine & "Line 4" & _
            vbNewLine & "Line 5" & _
            vbNewLine & "Line 6"

    With OutMail
        .To = strto
        .CC = strcc
        .BCC = strbcc
        .Subject = strsub
        .Body = strbody
    'You can add a file to the mail like this
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Display    ' or use .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What macro do you want to run on start up & what macro do you want to run when col G changes? Is this a certain cell in G, or any change in the column?

Comment: I want the first macro to run on start up because my sheet automatically updates with the day it is.

The first code will automatically call the mail code if any cells in row I = 100, 50, 10, or 1.

Then after this initial run, I want this to in if any cell in G changes.

Comment: The code will need to be on Worksheet and set event to Workbook_Open. You will need to qualify all of your ranges (Since the code will not be on a worksheet, you need to explicitly say what sheet)

Comment: You can run a code automatically when the workbook is opened by placing it in the `Workbook_Open()` procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a code automatically when the workbook is opened by calling it from the `Workbook_Open()` procedure.

The `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` procedure fires every time there's a chance, and then you can use the `Address` property of `Target` to see if the change was within `Column G`.

---

**In the ThisWorkbook module:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call YourProcedureName
End Sub
```

---

**In a Sheet module:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address Like "$G$*" Then
        Call YourProcedureName
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**In a regular module:**

```
Public Sub YourProcedureName()
    'Your code here
End Sub
```

Comment: It Works!! Thank you everyone so much!